# Functional testing of UI

Tags: testing

I am supposed to write functional test cases for a UI. Performance testing is out of scope.should I write Seperate test cases for each button, lets say review button which takes you to another page. So do we write them as seperate test cases or not .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure test cases are modular and test case steps are as granular as possible.

You can refer the [LINK](https://www.edureka.co/blog/test-case-in-software-testing/)